# XChangeProperty for an atom property on a system where Atom is 64 bits

Tags: x11, xlib

The X11 protocol defines an atom as a 32-bit integer, but on my system, the Atom type in  is a typedef for unsigned long, which is a 64-bit integer. The manual for Xlib says that property types have a maximum size of 32 bits. There seems to be some conflict here. I can think of three possible solutions.

1. If Xlib treats properties of type XA_ATOM as a special case, then you can simply pass 32 for 'format' and an array of atoms for 'data'. This seems unclean and hackish, and I highly doubt that this is correct.
2. The manual for Xlib appears to be ancient. Since Atom is 64 bits long on my system, should I pass 64 for the 'format' parameter even though 64 is not listed as an allowed value?
3. Rather than an array of Atoms, should I pass an array of uint32_t values for the 'data' parameter? This seems like it would most likely be the correct solution to me, but this is not what they did in some sources I've looked up that use XChangeProperty, such as SDL.

SDL appears to use solution 1 when setting the _NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE property, but I suspect that this may be a bug. On systems with little endian byte order (LSB first), this would appear to work if the property has only one element.

Has anyone else encountered this problem? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What SDL is doing is correct. The format specifies the number of bits used on the server, not how many are used in the Xlib interface. You always use an array of 'long' with format 32 no matter what and they are translated to 32 bits properly before being sent to the server.

32 and 64 bit clients may be connected to the same server and have to exchange information, so the format is the server side size.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the property routines you always want to pass an array of 'long', 'short' or 'char'. This is always true independent of the actual bit width. So, even if your long or atom is 64 bits, it will be translated to 32 bits behind the scenes.

The format is the number of server side bits used, not client side. So, for format 8, you must pass a char array, for format 16, you always use a short array and for format 32 you always use a long array. This is completely independent of the actual lengths of short or long on a given machine. 32 bit values such as Atom or Window always are in a 'long'.

This may seem odd, but it is for a good reason, the C standard does not guarantee types exist that have exactly the same widths as on the server. For instance, a machine with no native 16 bit type. However a 'short' is guaranteed to have *at least* 16 bits and a long is guaranteed to have *at least* 32 bits. So by making the client API in terms of 'short' and 'long' you can both write portable code and always have room for the full X id in the C type.